# How to remove " from Snowsql generated CSV file?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Using the below command generates CSV output with ". I am using windows. If already answered please share the post link.

```
snowsql -a <account> -u <username> -r accountadmin -d mydb -s myschema -q "select * from customer limit 20" -o output_file="e:\customer.csv" -o quiet=true -o friendly=false -o output_format=csv -o header=false -o timing=false
```

Sample output is as follows:

"C_CUSTKEY","C_NAME","C_ADDRESS","C_NATIONKEY","C_PHONE","C_ACCTBAL","C_MKTSEGMENT","C_COMMENT"
"1369097","Customer#001369097","jOccbXiKQLaDjnL1VlzTm","2","12-827-936-7420","6053.92","FURNITURE","ng packages cajole upon the slyly bold dolphins. fin"

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Is this output from the csv file? Can you post the table structure and the data that was inserted to it for review. I ran a simple test for a table which varchar and string columns, output for it to CSV does not show the strings in double-quotes.

Other Questions,Missing Document  fsa12
Next Row fsb1
third row ,fourth row fsb2

Comment: Use **output_format=pain** or **output_format=tsv** and you will get the output without quotes but with spaces/tabs rather than comma separated.

Comment: Well, taking clue from Sergiu's reply I modified the SQL as below and resolved the issue:   snowsql -a <a/c> -u <username>-r accountadmin -d mydb -s myschema -q "select c_custkey || ',' || c_name from customer limit 20" -o output_file="e:\customer.txt" -o quiet=true -o friendly=false -o output_format=plain -o header=false -o timing=false

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: **output_format=plain** works but there is whitespace padding at the end of the line, which may be annoying in some situations.
**output_format=tsv** (Tab Separated Values) works as well and removes the whitespace padding. I wish there was an option specifically for this